# Custom validator does not work in Spring RestController

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I have a library with a custom JSR349 validator defined as follows:

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ PARAMETER, FIELD, TYPE })
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidatorCipAut.class)
public @interface CipAut {

    String message() default "Error validando Cip Autonómico";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    boolean opcional() default false;
}
```

Validator:

```
public class ValidatorCipAut implements ConstraintValidator<CipAut, String> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValidatorCipAut.class);

    private boolean opcional;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CipAut constraintAnnotation) {...}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(
        String value,
        ConstraintValidatorContext context) {...}
}
```

I have used it in several projects and it works ok.

Now I am trying to use it in a Spring 3.0.4 project. The project incorporates *spring-boot-starter-web*, so it should include the dependences for *hibernate-validator*.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("alerts")
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class AlertsRest {
    @GetMapping(path="volant/{cipAut}/document")
    @RolesAllowed("AGNI_CONTACTS")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> volantDocument(
        @PathVariable(required = true) @CipAut String cipAut) {
        ...
    }
```

yet if I pass valid values it does not launch an error. OTOH, if I use one of the standard validations (e.g. *@Length(max = 11)*), the error is detected and the proper validation error is launched.

Additionally, I have tried using the same validator inside a bean that is passed to a component method, and it does not fail either:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CipAutBean {
    @CipAut
    private String cipAut;
}
```

```
@Component
@Validated
public class DummyComp {
    public void dummy(@Valid CipAutBean cipAutBean) {
        log.atWarn().log("CipAut es {}", cipAutBean.getCipAut());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could this be related to the SpringBoot 3 (and Java 17) move of javax.validation to jakarta.validation?

Comment: @JohnWilliams that was the issue. If you feel like posting as an answer I will check it; otherwise I will delete this question.

Comment: Thx - I converted to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the SpringBoot 3 (and Java 17) move of javax.validation to jakarta.validation?

Your custom validators will now need to extend or inherit from jakarta.validation, not javax.validation.